# In FaceBook Graph API v2.4, how can I include pictures/icons of the posts in the JSON feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm able to get JSON posts feed for a Public Group Page in FaceBook.  However, the feed is limited to the following:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "message": "RT Ad Age: Creatives rejoice! The need for speed in digital is putting copy testing under fire http://buff.ly/1NCNUYm",
         "created_time": "2015-09-16T19:17:22+0000",
         "id": "100893736659527_876911945724365"
      },
      {
         "message": "Smart Design Means Treating Your Users Like Friends.",
         "created_time": "2015-09-15T19:17:07+0000",
         "id": "100893736659527_876382499110643"
      },
      {
         "message": "Amazon Puts Another Nail in Flash\u2019s Coffin http://buff.ly/1NzwFal (via Digiday)",
         "created_time": "2015-09-14T17:25:52+0000",
         "id": "100893736659527_875881985827361"
      },
      {
         "message": "Is Belvedere Vodka Good Enough For James Bond?",
         "created_time": "2015-09-11T19:17:14+0000",
         "id": "100893736659527_874377899311103"
      },
      {
         "message": "RT MailChimp: Our GIPHY integration makes it easy to upload GIFs into your campaign. Exciting, right? http://buff.ly/1JQChqz",
         "created_time": "2015-09-10T19:17:14+0000",
         "id": "100893736659527_873864092695817"
      }
}
```

I'm able to get the message text, created_time, and id. How can I include pictures/icons of the post?

Comment: Ask for the fields in the request

Comment: @WizKid, my facebook request is as follows: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/[page-id]/feed?access_token=[access_token]`.  How do I add the  pictures field in the request?

Comment: You add fields=id,message and any other field you want

Comment: Go read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_changes, and pay specific attention to the section titled “declarative fields”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @WizKid responded above, this what worked for me: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/[page-id]/feed?access_token=[access_token]&fields=picture,id,message`